# Validation of model with incomplete data in Django

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I have a following use case in a project I'm working on.

Workflow looks like this:

- the system accepts proposed candidates (at this stage most fields are not required, email address can be invalid, etc.)
- their information can be corrected and updated
- some of the candidates get registered (now fields such as name and last name are required, email has to be valid, etc.)

I came up with two ideas.

One is to have two models for candidates. Then I could leverage automatic validation from Models and ModelForms but it would require copying instances from one model to the other while registering candidates and would bring problems in different places (for example with ForeignKeys).

Second idea is to have one model that accepts incomplete data and two ModelForms, one with redefined fields.

Both ideas require duplication of quite similar code.

Does anyone know about DRY and Django-style way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Please post an example

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a model for the proposed candidate info and another model for the final registered candidate, if you want to save the intermediate stage on the database and allow a user to edit it on another visit. Separate models for separate concerns. To reiterate your first option :)

Editing this as I realise it's all just rehashing your question. In this situation I'd stick with option 1, creating a new instance with the final candidate info when necessary. I'd probably link the final candidate to the proposed candidate instance with a foreign key and have `null=True` in the field definition, for the initial case. This would allow a cleanup task to run periodically and remove the proposed candidate instances where the data is duplicated for registered candidates. Or you could bite the bullet and remove the proposed instance upon a successful save of the final instance. Proceed with caution; you probably don't need to be thinking about removing stale data unless it becomes a problem, so I digress.

There's some slight duplication of code here, but not a great deal, and sometimes it's unavoidable if you want to reduce the potential for hairy application logic surprises.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a model without any database restrictions and then implement two different (Model)Forms.

Form A is used for the input of new objects. Thus, your Form A should not contain specific validation logic.

Form B on the other hand can hold all your validation logic and can be used to maintain data integrity.

Please note, that this approach will not guarantee database integrity. Your validation logic should be exposed to heavy unittesting.

Comment: Database integrity is more important than DRY

Comment: This corresponds with the stated second option I think. I'd avoid this approach because of the data integrity concerns. You don't want a situation where instances of a single model can represent both proposed and registered candidates. You could have an `is_registered` flag, however it just invites some application logic mess later on. With a separate model for final candidates, you can be sure that the data is valid for those instances.

Comment: Yeah, it's basically the second option, but I wanted to make clear that no "redefinition" of fields is necessary. Instead all can be handled in `clean`-methods (field and form). And yes, I would not sacrifice database integrity myself, but defining two nearly identical models seems wrong, too.

Comment: Redefinition of the fields to override the default arguments is the approach encouraged by the Django docs. In my days as a junior dev I might have considered a metaclass or custom `__init__` method based approach (can't remember if both would work, or only the first one) to iterate through a list of optional fields and override their attributes on the fly. However, this would be a hindrance in terms of discernibility and I wouldn't touch it now -- unless the number of optional fields was very high.